# Combine counts from multiple numpy.uniques

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, performance, numpy-indexing

I have *multiple* returns of [`numpy.unique(a, return_counts=True)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and unfortunately do *not* have access to the original arrays. I want to combine these results to one array with the unique values and to one storing the respective counts.
I do not want to create the arrays reversely by using [`np.repeat()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) , since these data is too big for my RAM.

I also found Python's [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) but since I'm using the results as numpy-arrays, I would prefer to stay "within" numpy. (Except, you would advise me to do it?)

Is there a *efficient* way to solve this problem?

I want something like this, without using `np.repeat()`:

```
mmulti_unique_values = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])
multi_unique_counts = np.array([[2,2,2,2],[1,2,3,1],[1,1,2,3],[1,2,2,1]])

values_ravel = multi_unique_values.ravel()
counts_ravel = multi_unique_counts.ravel()

np.unique(np.repeat(values_ravel,counts_ravel), return_counts=True)

> (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 7, 9, 7]))
```

I can achieve my desired result using a for-loop, but I'm looking for a (much) faster way!

```
all_unique_values, indices_ = np.unique(values_ravel, return_inverse=True)

all_unique_counts = np.zeros(all_unique_values.shape)

for count_index, unique_index in enumerate(indices_):
    all_unique_counts[unique_index] += counts_ravel[count_index]
    
(all_unique_values, all_unique_counts)
> (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5., 7., 9., 7.]))
```

Comment: The first result of `np.unique` is a sorted array which is not the case in your example which means the input does not come from `np.unique` as previously stated. Please clarify this point.

Comment: That's correct! That was my mistake in creating the dummie data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply apply `np.unique` to get the array with all the unique values and get at the same time the location for each item in the sorted array. Then you can accumulate the number of items based on the previous index so to get the merged number of item.

```py
all_unique_values, index = np.unique(multi_unique_values, return_inverse=True)
all_unique_counts= np.zeros(all_unique_values.size, np.int64)
np.add.at(all_unique_counts, index, multi_unique_counts.ravel())  # inplace
all_unique_counts
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an elegant solution!